# Xcode help - Upgrade current target for iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, ios4

I upgraded current target for iPad (to try and make a universal app) without making any changes and it doesn't seem to have worked. The only .xib file that was added to the iPad resources folder was MainWindow-iPad.xib, and no others.

Anyway disregarding that I tried to switch the active executable to ipad simulator. It runs but the layout has gone completely crazy. I can't fix it because there is no .xib in the iPad resources folder. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your other NIB files manually. Interface Builder has a menu command to get you started. Just open all your NIBs one after the other, convert them to iPad dimensions and save them under a new name. Then, in your code, make sure that you load the correct NIB file depending on the platform your app runs on.